# Set and remove a custom serializer in @JsonSerialize annotation

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I am converting a JSON into a java object. Several fields in my java object class use a custom serializer that I have defined. For example:

```
@JsonProperty("table_name")
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
private String tableName;
```

I only want to use my custom serializer in certain instances. Is there a way to set `using =` in the `@JsonSerialize` annotation?

I have the following JacksonAnnotationIntrospector in my ObjectMapper:

```
private static final JacksonAnnotationIntrospector ignoreCustomSerializer = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
    @Override
    protected <A extends Annotation> A _findAnnotation(final Annotated annotated, final Class<A> annoClass) {
        if (!annotated.hasAnnotation(JsonSerialize.class)) {
            return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annoClass);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

`objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(ignoreCustomSerializer);`

This introspector causes my object mapper to ignore all fields wit the `@JsonSerialize` annotation. I don't want to ignore the field, just the custom serializer I have set. Can the introspector be modified to change `using =` in the `@JsonSerialize` annotation?